# I have a MapsActivity and I need to link that to an ActivityBarFragment

Tags: java, android

Ok, so I'm kinda trying to develop an app with Android Studio, I'm actually a PHP dev and I'm trying to learn `Java`. Enough about me, I have a little diagram that'll explain better what I want to do! But, I'll explain it here anyways. I have a `MapsActivity` and I have a `FragmentActivity` and I want to pull the `MapsActivity` `fragment` and put it into the `FragmentActivity`. How can I go about doing that?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zxqeg.jpg

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MapsActivity` is not a fragment and has been deprecated for years. You should instead follow the [Getting Started with the Google Maps Android API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start) which uses [MapFragment](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapFragment)  - you can instead use [SupportMapFragment](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/SupportMapFragment) if you want to use `FragmentActivity`.

Comment: Thanks dude!I used the MapFragment thing and now it works. Thank you so much.